# How to build a function implicitly in Coq?

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove that every group has an inverse function.

I have defined a group as follows:

```
Record Group:Type := {
G:Set;
mult:G->G->G;
e:G;
assoc:forall x y z:G, mult x (mult y z)=mult (mult x y) z;
neut:forall x:G, mult e x=x /\ mult x e=x;
inverse:forall x:G,exists y:G, mult x y = e
}.
```

I am aware that it is better to just replace the inverse axiom by `inverse:forall x:G, {y: mult x y = e}.`, or even `inverse:G->G. is_inverse:forall x:G, mult x (inverse x)=e.`, but I prefer my definition, mainly because I want the definition to be identical to the one given in a classroom.

So I have included a suitable version of the axiom of choice:

```
Axiom indefinite_description : forall (A : Type) (P: A->Prop), ex P -> sig P.
Axiom functional_choice : forall A B (R:A->B->Prop), (forall x, exists y, R x y) -> (exists f, forall x, R x (f x)).
```

Now I can prove my claim:

```
Lemma inv_func_exists(H:Group):exists inv_func:G H->G H, (forall x:G H, mult H x (inv_func(x))=e H).
generalize (inverse H).
apply functional_choice.
Qed.
```

Now that I have proved the existence, I would like to define an actual function. Here I feel that things start to go messy. The following definition creates an actual function, but seems to ugly and complicated:

```
Definition inv_func(H:Group):G H->G H.
pose (inv_func_exists H).
pose indefinite_description.
generalize e0 s.
trivial.
Qed.
```

Lastly, I would like to prove that inv_func is actually an inverse function:

```
Lemma inv_func_is_inverse:forall (H:Group), forall x:(G H), mult H x (inv_func H x)=e H.
```

I can see that Coq knows how inv_func was defined (e.g. `Print inv_func`), but I have no idea how to formally prove the lemma.

To conclude, I would appreciate suggestions as to how to prove the last lemma, and of better ways to define inv_func (but under my definition of group, without including the existence of such a function in the group definition. I believe the question could be relevant in many other situations when one can prove some correspondence for each element and needs to build this correspondence as a function).

Comment: `functional_choice` follows from the `indefinite_description` axiom: `Proof.
  intros A B R H.
  exists (fun (x : A) => proj1_sig (indefinite_description _ (H x))).
  intro x.
  apply (proj2_sig (indefinite_description _ (H x))).
Qed.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few questions inside your question. I'll try to address all of them:

- First, there is no reason to prefer `exists x, P` + description over `{x | P}`, indeed, it seems weird you do so. `{x | P}` is perfectly valid as "there exists a `x` that can be computed" and I would rather use that definition with your groups.
- Secondly, when creating definitions using tactics, you should end the proof with the command `Defined`. Using `Qed` will declare the definition "Opaque", which means it cannot be expanded, then preventing you proof.
- The way to extract the witness from your definition is by using a projection. In this case, `proj1_sig`.

Using all the above we arrive at:

```
Definition inv_func' (H:Group) (x : G H) : G H.
Proof.
destruct (inverse H x) as [y _].
exact y.
Defined.

Definition inv_func (H:Group) (x : G H) : G H := proj1_sig (inverse H x).

Lemma inv_func_is_inverse (H:Group) (x: G H) : mult H x (inv_func H x) = e H.
Proof. now unfold inv_func; destruct (inverse H x). Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks @ejgallego. Your code works for me. However, I still don't understand something. Using my original code (with Qed replaced by Defined in the Definition), the tactic `unfold inv_func.` yields the goal `forall (H : Group) (x : G H), mult H x x = e H`, which is just wrong. Why is the reason for that?

Comment: @tomjerry7 this is because the `trivial` tactic is picking an arbitrary witness to conclude the proof. In this case, it picks the input element of the group.

Comment: OK. Thanks for detailed answer, that was very helpful.